# convert date in time and add 30 minutes in it using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project in which I have to split all date in array. so I get the time in hours and minutes variable. Time is like `'2015-11-07E05:02:50.631Z'`.

```
var res = ev_time.split("E");
var t=res[1].split(":");
var time1 =t[0] + ":" + t[1];
alert(time1);
var time2=time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + 30);
alert(time2);
```

when I Ignore last 2 line get correct result but when I using them I don't get the result. I want to add 30 minutes in time so I need to do that. How it will be possible?

Comment: As a side note, I really like using Moment.js for working with date/times in Javascript: http://momentjs.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here either `time1` or `time2` are not date objects and you can't access time1.getMinutes or setMintutes. You need to parse it to Date object before accessing these methods. If you just need to get desired output below code would be enough without any additional library.

```js
var ev_time='2015-11-07E05:02:50.631Z';
var res = ev_time.split("E");
var t=res[1].split(":");
var time1 =t[0] + ":" + t[1];
console.log(time1);

var time2 = new Date();
time2.setHours(t[0],t[1]);
time2.setMinutes(time2.getMinutes() + 30);
console.log(addZero(time2.getHours())+":"+addZero(time2.getMinutes()));

function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need

```
 time2=time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + 30);
```

time1.setMinutes() sets the value on time1, so if you do

```
time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + 30);
alert(time1)
```

You'll get the result

Comment: Is there no need to convert it in time because time1 is 05:02, so may be time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + 30); not worked

Comment: You need to convert it to a date object if it is not one. var time2 = new Date(time1); time2.setMinutes(time2.getMinutes() + 30);